# django paypal ipn - how should I know that a payment process has been started?

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

I'm trying to implement a checkout system with django-paypal. The system is working, but regarding the work flow I am quiet confused. django-paypal uses a form to post to PayPal, only after the payment has been processed I get a notification via IPN. Unfortunately this does take a lot of time (going from seconds to minutes).

Now it would be nice to log a pending state in my database so that I could tell the user to wait until the IPN has been received... but as django-paypal posts directly to PayPal and gives no feedback to my server I am stuck as there is no information being sent to the server. I could implement a switch to "pending" when opening the return url, but a GET shouldn't modify the state if the database...

Answer (score 0):

Solution to me was to also add the PayPal PDT. They are not exclusive. Both IPN and PDT can be called from the same form.